# How to find and separate string values within text files using java?

Tags: java, string, file, linked-list

For this java program, I have to read in three string values; an SSN, last name, and first name from a text file to create 1000 nodes. Then, later on create a skip list. However, I'm getting stumped(or forgetting) how to read an these values for the SSN, last name, and first name string variables.  The text file is like this and I realize the character break is going to be the ';' and press on to the next line.

510421600;Shelley;Morgan

790701850;Holton;Jose

932371897;Hynes;Naomi

714797789;Kunkel;Dylan

878566780;Grisham;Ellie

Here is what I have for my Node class thus far.

```
package list;

import java.io.File;

/** * Represents the nodes and list of SSNs * @author Adam Taylor * @version 1.1 */

public class Node
{
    /**
     * The last name of the person
     */
    public String lastName;

    /**
     * The first name of the person
     */
    public String firstName;

    /**
     * The SSN of the person
     */
    public String SSN;

    /**
     * The head of the node
     */
    public Node head;

    /**
     * The tail of the node
     */
    public Node tail;

    /**
     * The node pointers
     */
    public Node Link1, Link2, Link3, Link4;

    /**
     * The NodeObject
     */
    public Node next;

    public Node(int i, int j, int k)
    {
        File file = new File("Database.txt");

    }

    public String getSSN()
    {
        return "";
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "SSN:" + SSN + " Last Name: " + lastName + " First Name: " + firstName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .split() method of the String class.  It makes an array of strings based of a regular expression passed as a parameter.

To split at ";" and new lines you can use:

```
stringVar.split(";|\n");
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html?is-external=true